# C source won't compile for ARM architecture

Tags: android, c, gcc, makefile, android.mk

I'm developing a simple executable that is supposed to run during the Android system boot. It uses a small [tinydir.h](https://github.com/cxong/tinydir/blob/master/tinydir.h) library to go through files in a specific directory. And even though it compiles just fine for x86 and x86_64 (using gcc on OS X), when I try to build it with the Android system itself (for ARM), I get the following output:

```
target StaticExecutable: preparefs (out/target/product/hammerhead/obj/EXECUTABLES/preparefs_intermediates/LINKED/preparefs)
out/target/product/hammerhead/obj/lib/crtbegin_static.o:crtbrand.c:function _start: error: undefined reference to '__libc_init'
out/target/product/hammerhead/obj/lib/crtbegin_static.o:crtbrand.c:function atexit: error: undefined reference to '__cxa_atexit'
bionic/libc/include/string.h:178: error: undefined reference to 'memset'
system/core/preparefs/tinydir.h:262: error: undefined reference to 'free'
system/core/preparefs/tinydir.h:274: error: undefined reference to 'closedir'
system/core/preparefs/tinydir.h:286: error: undefined reference to '__errno'
system/core/preparefs/tinydir.h:291: error: undefined reference to '__errno'
system/core/preparefs/tinydir.h:298: error: undefined reference to 'readdir'
system/core/preparefs/main.c:23: error: undefined reference to 'malloc'
system/core/preparefs/main.c:61: error: undefined reference to 'memcpy'
system/core/preparefs/main.c:64: error: undefined reference to 'system'
bionic/libc/include/string.h:121: error: undefined reference to 'strcpy'
system/core/preparefs/tinydir.h:160: error: undefined reference to 'opendir'
system/core/preparefs/tinydir.h:164: error: undefined reference to '__errno'
system/core/preparefs/tinydir.h:171: error: undefined reference to 'readdir'
system/core/preparefs/tinydir.h:331: error: undefined reference to '__errno'
system/core/preparefs/main.c:75: error: undefined reference to 'strcmp'
bionic/libc/include/string.h:238: error: undefined reference to '__strlen_chk'
bionic/libc/include/string.h:229: error: undefined reference to 'strlen'
bionic/libc/include/string.h:121: error: undefined reference to '__strcpy_chk'
bionic/libc/include/string.h:168: error: undefined reference to '__strcat_chk'
bionic/libc/include/string.h:121: error: undefined reference to '__strcpy_chk'
bionic/libc/include/string.h:168: error: undefined reference to '__strcat_chk'
system/core/preparefs/tinydir.h:371: error: undefined reference to 'stat'
bionic/libc/include/string.h:276: error: undefined reference to '__strrchr_chk'
bionic/libc/include/string.h:238: error: undefined reference to '__strlen_chk'
system/core/preparefs/main.c:75: error: undefined reference to 'strcmp'
system/core/preparefs/main.c:82: error: undefined reference to 'system'
system/core/preparefs/main.c:85: error: undefined reference to 'system'
bionic/libc/include/string.h:121: error: undefined reference to 'strcpy'
bionic/libc/include/string.h:168: error: undefined reference to '__strcat_chk'
bionic/libc/include/string.h:168: error: undefined reference to '__strcat_chk'
system/core/preparefs/main.c:90: error: undefined reference to 'system'
system/core/preparefs/main.c:92: error: undefined reference to 'fopen'
system/core/preparefs/main.c:94: error: undefined reference to 'fseek'
system/core/preparefs/main.c:95: error: undefined reference to 'ftell'
system/core/preparefs/main.c:96: error: undefined reference to 'fclose'
system/core/preparefs/main.c:98: error: undefined reference to 'fopen'
system/core/preparefs/main.c:99: error: undefined reference to 'malloc'
system/core/preparefs/main.c:100: error: undefined reference to 'fread'
system/core/preparefs/main.c:101: error: undefined reference to 'fclose'
bionic/libc/include/string.h:238: error: undefined reference to '__strlen_chk'
system/core/preparefs/main.c:113: error: undefined reference to 'strcmp'
system/core/preparefs/main.c:129: error: undefined reference to 'time'
bionic/libc/include/stdio.h:387: error: undefined reference to 'snprintf'
bionic/libc/include/string.h:121: error: undefined reference to 'strcpy'
system/core/preparefs/main.c:140: error: undefined reference to '__stack_chk_fail'
system/core/preparefs/main.c:140: error: undefined reference to '__stack_chk_guard'
/tmp/AOSP-toolchain/build/../gcc/gcc-4.8/libgcc/unwind-arm-common.inc:289: error: undefined reference to 'abort'
/tmp/AOSP-toolchain/build/../gcc/gcc-4.8/libgcc/unwind-arm-common.inc:346: error: undefined reference to 'memcpy'
/tmp/AOSP-toolchain/build/../gcc/gcc

-4.8/libgcc/unwind-arm-common.inc:376: error: undefined reference to 'memcpy'
/tmp/AOSP-toolchain/build/../gcc/gcc-4.8/libgcc/unwind-arm-common.inc:505: error: undefined reference to 'abort'
/tmp/AOSP-toolchain/build/../gcc/gcc-4.8/libgcc/config/arm/pr-support.c:378: error: undefined reference to 'abort'
/tmp/AOSP-toolchain/build/../gcc/gcc-4.8/libgcc/config/arm/pr-support.c:384: error: undefined reference to 'abort'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [out/target/product/hammerhead/obj/EXECUTABLES/preparefs_intermediates/LINKED/preparefs] Error 1

#### make failed to build some targets (06:00 (mm:ss)) ####
```

And here's the Android.mk file I use:

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE:= preparefs

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := main.c

LOCAL_CFLAGS += -std=gnu99 -Wl,--start-group -lgcc -lc -lm -lrdimon -Wl,--end-group -fsigned-char -Wall -W -Wshadow -Wstrict-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-qual -Winline -Werror

LOCAL_FORCE_STATIC_EXECUTABLE := true
LOCAL_MODULE_PATH := $(TARGET_ROOT_OUT)/sbin
LOCAL_LDLIBS     += -llog -ldl 

include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)

include $(call first-makefiles-under,$(LOCAL_PATH))
```

Any ideas on what I can do to make it build?

Thanks in advance!

-- Edit:
Here's a stripped version of the main.c file that you can use to reproduce the issue:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tinydir.h>
#include <time.h> // don't mind the unnecessary imports, I removed some code to provide this sample

int main(void) {
    tinydir_dir dir;
    tinydir_open(&dir, "/directory");

    while (dir.has_next)
    {
        tinydir_file file;
        tinydir_readfile(&dir, &file);

        if(strcmp(file.name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(file.name, "..") == 0)
        {
            tinydir_next(&dir);
            continue;
        }
        if (file.is_dir)
        {
            return 1;
        }

        //doing something about the file

        tinydir_next(&dir);
    }

    tinydir_close(&dir);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a complete reproducable example? Why do you explicitly supply `-lc`?

Comment: `C executable won't compile for ARM architecture`. That is nonsense. One does not compile executables. You ment: `C source won't compile for ARM architecture` ?

Comment: @FUZxxl I've edited the post to include sample code. It's not the entire file that I use, but should be just enough. A lot of the flags used I've added trying to make the code work. I realise that most of them are unnecessary.

Comment: @greenapps I have indeed, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: I'm guessing you are not linking against the library that contains all the C standard library stuff such as strncpy.

Comment: it is simple.  where do you think the functions that are missing from the link step are located?  in a specific library, of course.  I'm thinking it is the lib6c.so library.   so, if it were me, I would add that library to the link step.

Comment: It might be useful to take a look at the Android.mk for `init` which is statically linked http://androidxref.com/5.1.0_r1/xref/system/core/init/Android.mk in particular you might drop your custom flags and try listing libc under LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES  (This of course concerns Android's bionic libc which does get used statically in a number of critical programs, unlike normal Linux glibc which has not really supported static linking for a long time now)

Answer (score 0):

These functions are part of libc, which is located in your arm toolchain's directory.  Likely your arm toolchain is not configured properly.   Check your toolchain directory and make sure that libc.so is indeed there, and do an `nm -g libc.a` (use the arm cross-compile version of nm, not the host version).   If the functions are not there, you may have to reconfigure/recompile your toolchain with the proper options.   If they are there, you'll have to ensure that you are trying to link against that library.

Comment: The poster is trying to build the code as part of an overall build of the Android system sources - a process which includes obtaining and utilizing a properly configured toolchain for cross-compiling to the target.  If there were problems with the installation, it would probably fail while building stock code, before getting to their customization.  Further, the code should be being built against a locally compiled version of Bionic libc, rather than one shipped with something like the NDK.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I'd say if you use the NDK you will be using Bionic.